# definir a função

Tags: c

estou fazendo um exercício de linguagem c e queria saber se alguém pode me ajudar a entender como eu faço essa função, sem adição de biblioteca
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu não faço ideia de como escrever ela no programa,a minha duvida é como eu elevo expoentes ao quadrado nesses tipos de exercícios, minha ideia primaria, é que cada sequencia vai se multiplicando por números impares, EX: 1/3+ 1/6*1/6*1/6, o 1 terço tem 1, 1 sexto tem 3 , 1 nono tem 5

```
int main(){
  float p=1;
  int n,r,denominador=1;
//entrada de dados
  printf("escreva o números de termos a serem somados= \n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
//função
  for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
    denominador*=3;
    p= p + i/denominador;
  }
}
```

Comment: Pesquise sobre a função `pow` da linguagem C.

Comment: a eu esqueci de especificar q ele pede sem adição de biblioteca,perdão

Answer (score 2):

Da matemática básica, lembramos que para inverter o sinal de um expoente, podemos inverter a fração da base. Ou seja, x^(-2) é o mesmo que (1/x)^2, sendo ^ o sinal de potenciação.

Assim, podemos reescrever a sua expressão de forma que:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou ainda...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que, matematicamente poderá ser reescrito como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se definirmos uma função para o termo da somatória, `f(i)`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podemos dizer que:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Assim, para reescrevermos em C, basta percorrermos em um laço de repetição de 1 a n, acumulando o valor de `f(i)`.

```c
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  fdp += f(i);
}
```

Restando apenas implementarmos `f(i)` em C:

```
float f(int i) {
  float numerator = 3*i;
  float denominator = 1;

  while (i > 0) {
    denominator *= (3*i)*(3*i);
  }

  return numerator / denominator;
}
```

Imagino que com isso você consiga dar seguimento na solução.

Comment: obrigado, era isso q eu estava em duvida.

Answer (score -1):

Tente algo do tipo:

```
float soma=0;
int pot=1;
for(i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    pot *= 3 * 3;
    soma += (i*3) * (1/pot);
}
```